# Why ConfirmCallback#confirm#CorrelationData has only one property id rather than the entire message so that i can resend message immediately

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying some stuff about Reliability of message delivery using `ConfirmCallback`.

So far I've done these:

1.When I send a message, I save it in the db (There is a field called status that indicates whether the message reached the broker successfully). Message id will stored in correlationData.

2.Using ConfirmCallback, if ack, i will update Message#status to success.( I can get message id from CorrelationData )

3.Using timed tasks to find the message that was not sent successfully, and resend.

I wonder why `ConfirmCallback#confirm#CorrelationData` has only one property id rather than the entire message so that I can resend message immediately.(In this way I don't need to persist messages).

Is there any other way to ensure that the message is sent successfully?

Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sub-class `CorrelationData` to add the message.

Comment: Thanks! By the way,Is there any other better way to ensure that the message is sent successfully? Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "better". Negative confirms are rare (unless the queue has a message limit and the overflow behavior is `reject-publish`. Often enabling returned messages for unroutable messages is enough, but to be sure messages are routed to at least one queue, confirms are useful.

Comment: It's possible that the broker is suddenly dead? I'll get  Negative confirms in this case.

Comment: The documentation used to say that nacks were exceptional and indicate a bug in the broker (I can't find that now). However, it is true that Spring will synthesize nacks for any un-ack'd messages when it detects that a channel is closed.